# Is there anyways to center text made with pyfiglet?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried centering text made with pyfiglet using the built in center() but it won't work.

Any workarounds?

my code:

```
from pyfiglet import figlet_format
import shutil

x = figlet_format("mogus", font = "standard")

print(x.center(shutil.get_terminal_size()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is :)

You canuse the `justify` keyword on the pyfiglet.figlet_format method.

For example

```py
centered_text = pyfiglet.figlet_format("mogus", font="standard", justify="center")
```